# Find and describe all relative extrema

Tags: calculus

I've encountered this question: Find and describe all local extrema of $ f(x) = x^{5
/3} − 5x^{2/3}$. Also indicate on which regions the function is increasing and decreasing.

Using the derivative, I found the minimum at x = 2. But when I graphed the function, I saw that it goes up to zero and seems to have a maximum here. Is it really an extrema? Why didn't it show up with the derivative?

Thanks!

Comment: Which function did you plot ? There is a minimum for $x=2$ not a maximum.

Comment: In fact you function is defined on  $ [0, \infty) $, and its derivative is defined in   $ (0, \infty) $. So when you find the derivative you check for extrema in the interior of the domain of  $f$, you still need to check if you have extrama at the boundaries. So you are right $0$ is a local max.

Comment: Why is it only defined on (0, +inf) ?

Comment: Shouldn't the function be defined for all real numbers?

Comment: For negative $x$ $x^{1/3}$ is multivalued.